# A sly expression for a 'one day chance meeting'

Tags: idioms, phrase-request, expressions

Considering a situation where I once met a guy **just for a day** and we somehow developed a bond due to the circumstances we were in—helping each other and sharing mutual ideas... but never remained in touch after that and 
now out of nowhere we meet again? To answer the curious people but not wanting to expound upon it, I wan't to escape the question 
**..with a mischievous one liner** which would leave the people wondering ***what must have happened?***
Also it should not give a wrong implication.
Something like 'we have a history' or 'we go way back' sort of expressions. But I can't use them due to this link:  [Meaning of 'We have a history'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117328/meaning-of-we-have-a-history).

I'm considering

> We've had a good time together.

But that would mean 'had a good time' for more than a day.

I'm counting on you experts to provide me with suitable expressions to clear out this **'one day chance meeting of good memories'** situation.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

There's this idiom: **ships that pass in the night**. [One online dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ships-that-pass-in-the-night) defines it as:

> **ships that pass in the night** (*idiom*) Often said of people who meet for a brief but intense moment and then part, never to see each other again. These people are like two ships that greet each other with flashing lights and then sail off into the night. From a poem by Henry Wadsworth Longfellow.

If you have met this person again, then the idiom is no longer an exact fit. However, you could reference the idiom by saying:

> *Our ships passed one night*.

I'd interpret that to mean that you had your chance encounter in the past, and that, at the time, you didn't really expect to run into each other again.

I don't believe that's a standard way to use the idiom, but I'd regard it as an acceptable usage. I also don't think there's any problem with using "night," even if your prior meeting was a daytime encounter.

Comment: +1 Wow! I didn't know about that idiom. I knew I'd find something good here. Thanks, I'll consider that..